# Creating a feedforwardnet model in Matlab

Tags: matlab, feed-forward

I'd like to implement a model that works like this:
it gets 3 inputs, for example - 1,2,3
and it gives 1 output - a number between 0 to 1 (including 0 and 1).
The model is a feedforwardnet- at first, it "trains" - it gets inputs and results, and then, based on his training, it can give a result where only the inputs are given, for example:
one time he got 1,2,3 and result: 0,
second time he got 2,3,4 and result: 0,
third time he got 3,4,5 and result: 1.
fourth time he got 4,5,6 but no result - so based on his knowledge and algorithm, he would give a result, let's say: 0.45.

My problem is that the size of the vector of the inputs and the size of the vector of the results must be equal, so the vector of the results must contain 3 elements when I only need 1 - so I made all the elements the same, meaning: it gets [1 1 1] or [0 0 0] ( I hope it's not ruining the network).
Anyway, this is the code of my model - did I implement it well? because I'm not sure...

```
% x1 is the input in the 1st case, x2 is the input in the 2nd case...
% t1 is the result in the 1st case, t2 is the result in the 2nd case...
net=feedforwardnet(1);
x1=[1 2 3];
t1=[0 0 0];
x2=[2 3 4];
t2=[0 0 0];
x3=[3 4 5];
t3=[1 1 1];
x4=[4 5 6];
net=train(net,x1,t1);
net=train(net,x2,t2);
net=train(net,x3,t3);
t4=net(x4)
```

Answer (score 1):

No，it should be trained one once and the multiple case should be put into only ONE matrix

```
the right program should be as follows:
x = [x1', x2', x3'];
t = [0 0 1];
net = train(net, x, t);
t4 = net(x4)
```